# Less costly /neatest way to use selectfield properties as key relationships for ndb

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, flask, app-engine-ndb, flask-wtforms

I'm having trouble modeling key/parents for the last two (sensors/readings). I'd like to keep the ancestor path for each. The problem is I only have access to the last id in the hierarchy. Does this require me to do complex query's each time or is there an easier way ?

In any case the hierarchy I'm trying to keep is:

> Home -> Zone -> Sensor -> Readings

To test it out I have made a few forms. The selectfield for each form is done like this:

```
form.zonekey.choices = [ (h.key.id(),h.sensortype)for h in Sensor.query()]
```

I realize using the id/key is not secure since it shows up in the html form but I have no idea how to do this other than hashing the id along the way.

My problem is that I can't use the above ID selected from the form to lookup the zone key and parents since the key is comprised of Zone and Home keys and I don't know what those are. Looking up the zone by

ndb.Key(Zone, ID) doesn't seem to work (because the key actually includes Homekey and I don't know that there).

Is my only choice to do a query like this:

```
Zone.query().filter(Zone.zname == 'zonetest1')
```

and get the key to that and use that as the parent for the next level in the hierarchy(Sensor).

That seems a costly, and convoluted way. Is there an easier and more elegant way to do this ?

Here are pictures of my tests and results.

[image: Zone Form I created]

[image: Sensor Form I created (showing selectfield)]

[image: Readings Form I created]

[image: List of inputs I locally tested. To show the key features]

Comment: Please understand that it is very difficult for anyone who isn't already familiar with your particular model to follow this question. You also seem to have a few issues here: one is querying from the database, and the second is displaying values on a form. Try the following: just pick the optimal way to do one subject (say, writing the query), then rephrase your question as to how to do the other subject (make the form) in a way that allows you access to the data that you say you otherwise wouldn't have.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the clarification. Indeed it's a two prong problem with flask. The first is creating a selectfield (choices) from a query. One that is persistent/secure. The other is being able to retrieve the data securely. I have finally created a way of mapping the choices to numeric keys. Now i'm trying to figure out how to save them in-between requests.